# Unexpected Entity Reference Autocomplete behaviour

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Entity API, Form API and Entity Reference Autocomplete in Drupal.
I have a relationship between two types, clubs and courses, each `club` can have many `courses` so basically the table `course` contains a column called `goclid` which references the `club` id number like so:

```
// hook_schema()

$schema['course'] = array(
    // other fields...
'goclid' => array(
    'description' => 'Reference to the club',
    'type' => 'int',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => TRUE,
  ),

// ... a few lines later...
'foreign key' => array(
  'related_club' => array( // join alias
    'table' => 'club',
    'columns' => array('goclid' => 'id'),
  ),
),
// etc.
);
```

Then I include a field like so in the `course` form:

```
$form['goclid'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Reference to the club'),
    '#type' => 'entityreference',
    '#era_entity_type' => 'club',
    '#default_value' => isset($course->goclid) ? $course->goclid : '',
    '#required' => FALSE,
);
```

Now, the autocomplete gives suggestions only when I type an id number, and then populates the field value with the label (name of the golf club). 
What I want is exactly the opposite: I want to get suggestions by typing the name of the club, and then when I choose one, the form field should be populated with the id number of that object.

Why is Entity Reference Autocomplete behaving in an unexpected way? What can I do to obtain the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Salvador Molina](http://adevfromtheplains.com/), the author of the Entity Reference Autocomplete Module, [gave me an answer on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166398/unexpected-entity-reference-autocomplete-behaviour) which is worth sharing also here on Stackoverflow:

> I think you might have not specified the "label" column in the entity definition. That goes within the 'entity keys' array, like the 'id' key.

```
$entity_info = array(
   .....
  'entity keys' array(
    'id' => 'primary key column...',
    'label' =>  'column holding the label'
  ),
)
```

> Otherwise entityreference will not know which column to use for searching in the DB. That still makes it possible to show the label (as you're experiencing) after you reference the entity, because 'label' key is not mandatory, and you may have specified a "label callback" instead, which the Entity API will use when entity_label() is called to get the label of a specific entity.

Salvador's hint worked flawlessly, after including `label` in the `entity keys` array I can search entities by typing their label.

Answer (score 1):

Check here [Link to readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/entityreference_autocomplete/tree/README.txt)

you will se this:

```
$form['my_entity_reference'] = array(
      '#type' => 'entityreference',
      '#title' => t('My Reference'),
      '#era_entity_type' => 'user',  // Mandatory.
      '#era_bundles' => array(), // Optional (Any bundle by default).
      '#era_cardinality' => 3,       // Optional (1 By default).
      '#era_query_settings' => array(
        'limit' => 15, // Default is 50.
        'property_conditions' => array(
          // 'entity property', 'filter value', 'operator'.
          array('uid', 30, '>'),
        ),
        'field_contitions' => array(
          // 'field name', 'column', 'value', 'op', 'delta', 'language'.
          array('field_test_field', 'value', 'test'),
        ),
      ),
    );


          - 'field_conditions':  Allows to filter the results returned in
                      the query, based on the value of any field of the of
                      the entity. This property is meant to be an array, in
                      which each element is an array of the arguments to
                      pass to the fieldCondition() method of the
                      EntityFieldQuery class.
                      Example of use:

                            '#era_query_settings' => array(
                              'field_conditions' => array(
                                // 'field name', 'column', 'value'.
                                array('field_test_field', 'value', 'test'),
                              ),
                            ),

                      For further information, see the documentation of the
                      fieldCondition() method of the EntityFieldQuery class
```

Hope its solves your question :)

Comment: Hi Cesar thank you very much for pointing that out, actually I had already checked the readme file but your answer is still very useful for future reference because sometimes people forget to check readme files in modules. However my problem was not related to the information found in the readme, I contacted the author of the Entity Reference Autocomplete module and he gave me the right clue, so I'm now posting a "self answer" here for future reference.